# select top values from table

Tags: c#, sql, select

I run the following query from C#:

```
SELECT TOP 100 colNamae FROM tableName
```

If the number of rows in the table is less that 100 -  should I treat it in some way?(as catch exception etc)
While testing nothing happened - any error.

Comment: it will get the all records if they are less than 100 no error will come

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: harsh votedown ... he is asking if there is something else he needs to *consider*. Yalkov move this to code review. Here you will just get abuse from people who can because they can. The answer is no btw - you do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No , what you are doing is perfectly fine.